# UIRotationGestureRecognizer minimum rotation value

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to set a minimum rotation value necessary for a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to transition into `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`?  I'm using multiple recognizers, and my `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` keeps getting called with a very small rotation (Between 1 and 15 degrees either direction) rather than my `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.

What I'd like to do is only have the rotation be called if the rotation is within a certain range, otherwise cancel it and let the pinch be called.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't such a method.

However, you can check [the `.rotation` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIRotationGestureRecognizer/rotation) of the gesture recognizer, and determine if you need to take any actions.

Comment: Yeah, I've been messing with that, I'm jut unsure of how to stop rotation from being recognized and call on the pinch recognizer.  I've checked out the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` method, but it seems to not work at all.

Comment: Yes of course.  I check the state of the rotation method I defined, and if it is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` I check the rotation value, and if it's within my range I call `[pinchRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:rotationRecognizer]` - this does not seem to do anything.